# Django profile - user adding some objects

Tags: django, django-models, profile

I want to have django user profile where the user can add some objects (he can add more than one) e.g. his addresses, his products and their descriptions and so on. I've no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to extend the user model via `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE`. There's a great tutorial (doing part of what you want) on James Bennett's [blog](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/06/django-tips-extending-user-model/).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new model (say UserProfile) with a ForeignKey to the User model.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    address = models.TextField()
    products = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```